# Connects to wifi but no internet access

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, realtek

Wifi is fine though, since my other ubuntu notebook connects without problems.
ethernet is working aswell (thats how im postinng here)

Ping:

```
snckrs@sculptor:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
131 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 131039ms
```

ifconfig:

```
snckrs@sculptor:~$ ifconfig
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:16:7e:34:1c:84  
          inet addr:192.168.178.43  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:810c:8400:608:fb11:e612:823b:83c3/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::c451:a4d5:d7a0:4508/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:810c:8400:608:a5e8:9c8c:fd02:427d/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1077 errors:0 dropped:103 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:291163 (291.1 KB)  TX bytes:160040 (160.0 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7200000-f7220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:186147 (186.1 KB)  TX bytes:186147 (186.1 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:27:1e:7a:1c:9d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:283 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:769 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:48736 (48.7 KB)  TX bytes:79586 (79.5 KB)
```

lshw (with PCI, as it is a PCIe card)

```
        *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
         version: d5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f7100000-f71fffff
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: wlp3s0
            version: 00
            serial: 54:27:1e:7a:1c:9d
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
            resources: irq:30 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7103fff
```

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your answer to include a link to it